# Transfer learning model not learning much, validation plateau at 45% while train go up to 90%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

i've been working on this model on image classification. I have 70000 images and 375 classes. I've tried training it with Vgg16, Xception, Resnet & Mobilenet ... and I always get the same limit of 45% on the validation.

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VntBG.png)

I've tried adding dropout layers and regularization and it gets the same result for validation.
Data augmentation didn't do much to help either
Any ideas why this isn't working ?

Here's a snipped of the code of the last model I used:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import regularizers
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
target_size = (height, width)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path,
    target_size=(height, width),
    batch_size=batchSize,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path,
    target_size=(height, width),
    batch_size=batchSize,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')

num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)



xception_model = Xception(weights='imagenet',input_shape=(width, height, 3), include_top=False,classes=num_classes)
x = xception_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

opt = Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


n_epochs = 15

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batchSize,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batchSize,
    verbose=1, 
    epochs = n_epochs)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add more layers? Or maybe increase the nodes. Is your dataet balanced? Have you tried to tinker learning rate? There are many things that can go wrong.

Comment: @GiorgosLivanos I did try to add 2 more layers but it didn't improve the validaiion accuracy.
The dataset is unbalanced though, here's a picture of the distribution among classes:
[link](https://postimg.cc/8sfcxBrN)

Comment: Have you tried to lower learning rate? Is your dataset public so I can replicate your code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may need a balanced dataset among each category in your dataset for better model training performance. Please try again by changing `class_mode='sparse'` and  `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` because you are using the image dataset. Also freeze the pretrained model layers `'xception_model.trainable = False'`.

Check the below code: (I have used a [flower dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#download_the_flowers_dataset) of 5 classes)

```
xception_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(weights='imagenet',input_shape=(width, height, 3), include_top=False,classes=num_classes)
xception_model.trainable = False
x = xception_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model = keras.Model(inputs=xception_model.input, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_generator,  epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
217/217 [==============================] - 23s 95ms/step - loss: 0.5945 - accuracy: 0.7793 - val_loss: 0.4610 - val_accuracy: 0.8337
Epoch 2/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 0.3439 - accuracy: 0.8797 - val_loss: 0.4550 - val_accuracy: 0.8419
Epoch 3/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 93ms/step - loss: 0.2570 - accuracy: 0.9150 - val_loss: 0.4437 - val_accuracy: 0.8384
Epoch 4/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 0.2040 - accuracy: 0.9340 - val_loss: 0.4592 - val_accuracy: 0.8477
Epoch 5/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 0.1649 - accuracy: 0.9494 - val_loss: 0.4686 - val_accuracy: 0.8512
Epoch 6/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 92ms/step - loss: 0.1301 - accuracy: 0.9589 - val_loss: 0.4805 - val_accuracy: 0.8488
Epoch 7/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 93ms/step - loss: 0.0966 - accuracy: 0.9754 - val_loss: 0.4993 - val_accuracy: 0.8442
Epoch 8/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 0.0806 - accuracy: 0.9806 - val_loss: 0.5488 - val_accuracy: 0.8372
Epoch 9/10
217/217 [==============================] - 20s 91ms/step - loss: 0.0623 - accuracy: 0.9864 - val_loss: 0.5802 - val_accuracy: 0.8360
Epoch 10/10
217/217 [==============================] - 22s 100ms/step - loss: 0.0456 - accuracy: 0.9896 - val_loss: 0.6005 - val_accuracy: 0.8360
```